# How to increase the template type int parameter?

Tags: c++

I got something like this:

```
template<int i>
struct s {};
```

And I need to write this:

```
s<1> a = inc<s<0>>;
```

I think it could be done with:

```
template<template<int I> typename S>
using inc = S<I + 1>;
```

But it doesn't works and gcc says that template parameter is invalid.

GCC 7, -std=c++14

Comment: Looks like you want `inc<s<0>>` to name a type - but then it doesn't make sense as an initializer; an expression is expected there. What are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: You might be thinking of something [like this](http://rextester.com/LYS30846). But again, it's not clear how you plan to use it.

Comment: Yes, I want to get a type similar as `s<0>`, but `s<1>` by writing `inc<s<0>>`.

Comment: You are right, thank you.

Comment: @NikolaySyukosev: So the syntax wouldn't be `s<1> a = inc<s<0>>;`, but would instead be `inc<s<0>> a;`, since, as you said, `inc<s<0>>` names the type.

Answer (score 0):

You approach cannot work, because you pass `s<0>` to `inc` which already is a full specialization of `s`.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>
#include <vector>

template < int i >
struct s {
    constexpr static int value = i;
};

template < typename S >
struct incrementer;

template < int i >
struct incrementer < s<i> >
{
    typedef s<i + 1> type;
};

template < typename S >
using inc = typename incrementer<S>::type;    

int main()
{
    s<1> a = inc<s<0>>{};
}
```

To work with the syntax from the question (i.e. without initialization braces) you need a [variable template from C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template).

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template < int i >
struct s {
    constexpr static int value = i;
};

template < typename S >
struct incrementer;

template < int i >
struct incrementer < s<i> >
{
    typedef s<i + 1> type;
};

template < typename S >
typename incrementer<S>::type inc = typename incrementer<S>::type{};    

int main()
{
    s<1> a = inc<s<0>>;
}
```